# Why doesn't the flange fit on a new bathroom faucet?

Tags: bathroom, sink, drain

I purchased a Kohler Mistos today for the bathroom sink. I took out the old faucet, struggled with the old drain assembly, but got that off with no damage to the sink.  I attempted to put in the new drain flange with plumber's putty and it wouldn't fit. I took a small box cutter and trimmed the ribs off the plastic and it still won't fit. I took the putty off, though it wasn't in the way, and it still didn't fit. I tried screwing the rest onto the flange and hoped I could use the plastic nut to pull it down.  That didn't work.  I don't know what else to do.

The box does have in small print drain assembly made in China.  Is this someone using metric and not standard measurement, machine off in production, or am I just not doing something right?

Comment: Are you having problems sink side with the pop-up half or underside with the drain attachment?  Porcelain or metal sink?

Answer (score 1):

These photos both show Mistos parts, which of the 2 pop-ups look like yours?  The top one is for commercial use, the bottom one residential.  Kohler will replace the top one, if that is what you have.

[image]

Drain units also different, commercial top, residential bottom

[image]